# mysql Search range by year

Tags: mysql, performance, date, search

I want to get the date of birth of a cat as a range of years.

The year range is as follows, and several selections are possible.

Year : [2000, 2010, 2020]

If I select 2020, the period from 2020-01-01 to 2029-12-31.

If I select 2000, 2020, the period from 2000-01-01 to 2009-12-31 and 2020-01-01 to 2029-12-31.

```
<TABLE>
CAT {
 ID number,
 Birth DateTime,
...
}
```

I have searched for various ways through books and Google, but I can't find the way I want to do so..

```
select * from CAT 
where   birth between '2000-01-01' and '2009-12-31'
or      birth between '2010-01-01' and '2019-12-31'
or      birth between '2020-01-01' and '2029-12-31'
```

I tried to use 'Between' or '-01-01', but if [2000, 2020] is selected, it must be connected with 'or'.
The more or, the slower the speed.

Please tell me a good way to do range calculations being able to use index.
The index is being used for BirthDate.

Add) In my db, the query of 'SUBSTRING(YEAR(CAT.birth),1,3) IN (200,202)' works quickly.
I have 500,000 data, can I use it like this?

Comment: Can you put your data in some online database fiddle? and also could you please show your desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is add index to column `birth` and run your query above with `BETWEEN` and `OR`.

Comment: I wasn't sure about the lengthy query, thank you!

Comment: @KunAguero - "lengthy query" -- not a problem.  A query that is a million bytes is _beginning_ to be "lengthy".

Comment: `OR` almost always prevents the use of any `INDEX`.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using mysql, did you tried with YEAR() function ?

Example:
`SELECT * FROM cat WHERE YEAR(birth) BETWEEN 1990 AND 2018 ORDER BY YEAR(birth) ASC;`

Please check this [Mysql YEAR()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_year.asp)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But I can't use it like that. Because I need to be able to select 2000 and 2020 in a non-consecutive way.

Answer (score 0):

If you expect to get more than about 20% of the rows from a table, then an `INDEX` will be eschewed for simply scanning all the rows.

Otherwise, having `INDEX(birth)` will help with *certain* queries, but none of the ones mentioned so far.  Each of them is not ["sargable"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) .

To use the index (and be efficient for a limited range of years or date range), something like this is probably what you need.  This example covers 2 calendar years.

```
WHERE CAT.birth >= '2018-01-01'
  AND CAT.birth  < '2020-01-01'
```

BTW: `SUBSTRING(YEAR(CAT.birth),1,3)` can be simplified to `LEFT(CAT.birth, 3)`, but that still cannot use the recommended index.

BTW:  A 'bug' in your code:  Since `birth` is a `DATETIME`, `and '2009-12-31'` excludes but midnight of the morning of New Year's Eve.  Note how I avoided this common 'bug' by using `<` and the next day.  This works whether you have `DATE`, `DATETIME` or `DATETIME(6)`, etc.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I learned a lot. :)